# A Question on Brezis Functional Analysis Proposition 11.18.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I will attach the proposition and proof here:
[image]

[image]

I followed the proof until the last couple lines of the proof attached. My question is this: If we proved the the form of $\phi$ in a dense set, why does it extends to $\ell_p$? We would need to interchange limits and sums right? What guaranteed that switch of limit and sum to be safe to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u \in (\ell^{p'})$ we get a  continuous linear functional $\psi$ by defining $\psi (x)$ as $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} u_k x_k$ (with norm at most $\|u\|_{(\ell^{p'})}$. [This is a consequence of Holder's inequality]. Since $\phi =\psi$ on a dense set and $\phi, \psi$ are both continuous it follows that $\phi\equiv \psi$.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. According to the book notation, $u \in \ell^{p'}$ is in the sense that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'} = 1$. I am not entirely sure what you mean by $u \in (\ell^p)'$. Could you elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner That was a typo. I typed $(\ell^{p})'$ for $\ell^{p'}$.